# Angular 15 build strange behavior. Build sometine pass, sometime not without source code changes

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material, mdc-components, angular15

I have migrated an Angular App from Angular 14 to Angular 15.
Application use material.

The migration process was:

```
ng update @angular/core@15 @angular/cli@15
ng update @angular/material@15
```

After these steps, I update all third parties packages,
and I migrate from Material Legacy to Material MDC:

```
ng generate @angular/material:mdc-migration
```

After each of theses steps i build application to verify very thing is ok. And every things was ok until MDC migration.

Once the MDC migration done, appliation build is randomly ok or not.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

if i issue another build, it can be ok or not! It seems to be random and once again there is no change in source code between builds.

In case of error, the error is always the same:

```
./src/app/home/home.component.scss?ngResource - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: $map: null is not a map.
   ╷
10 │   @return map.get(map.get($config, $level), $name);
   │           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
  node_modules/@angular/material/core/typography/_typography-utils.scss 10:11  -mat-get-type-value()
  node_modules/@angular/material/core/typography/_typography-utils.scss 17:11  font-size()
  src/app/home/home.component.scss 34:16                                       root stylesheet
```

Ideas welcome!

Comment: Hi, did you found any solution. We have the same issue from time to time and it's completely random.

Comment: Yes! found solution, i will answer my question as soon as i have time to help you. Check this post!

Comment: checking every 5 minutes :)

Comment: Any news? Would be great to post your solution